# How can I send an XmlDocument to WCF service?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, xmldocument

I need to pass an XmlDocument from ASP.Net to a WCF service - how can I do this?

I think there is something to do in service contract and operation contract - I am new to this concept.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should consider looking through your other questions and marking those answers that you found helpful as "Accepted".

Comment: sure Kragen..I will do that shortly.

Answer (score 0):

stating this as an answer since I do not see the possibility to comment on the question.

it should be perfectly possible to send it across using a string (convert your xml to string and convert back inside your wcf service).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through XmlSerializer Class.
This is all you need, please read: [Using the XmlSerializer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx)

This also satisfies the members being serialized as attributes and elements just like an Xml document should be.

Instead of:

```
<Person>
     <Name>Peyton Crow</Name>
</Person>
```

You can have the control of making the "Name" property as attribute:

```
<Person Name="Peyton Crow" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the contents of the XmlDocument, one way is to declare an operation with an `XmlNode` parameter:

```
[OperationContract]
void MyOperation(XmlNode xml);
```

Then call it from the client as follows:

```
XmlDocument doc = ...
myService.MyOperation(doc.DocumentElement);
```

Comment: You cannot pass an XmlNode as a parameter via WCF, it would have to be an XmlElement for example, as the XmlNode is abstract.